# Как проверить содержится ли в строке какое-то слово из списка?

Tags: python, строки, list, список

Например есть список

```
words = ["Авто", "Велосипед", "Самолет"]
```

И например строка

```
str = "Быстрый автомобиль"
```

Нужно вернуть `True`, т.к. в строке есть "авто"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

используя регулярные выражения, можно сделать такую проверку без цикла:

```
In [12]: import re

In [13]: chk_pat = '(?:{})'.format('|'.join(words))

In [14]: chk_pat
Out[14]: '(?:Авто|Велосипед|Самолет)'

In [15]: s = "Быстрый автомобиль"

In [16]: bool(re.search(chk_pat, s, flags=re.I))
Out[16]: True

In [17]: bool(re.search(chk_pat, 'строка', flags=re.I))
Out[17]: False
```

PS если список слов проверки слишком большой 10+K bytes, то лучше, наверное,  такие длинные регулярные выражения не использовать

Answer (score 5):

```
def is_part_in_list(str_, words):
    for word in words:
        if word.lower() in str_.lower():
            return True
    return False
```

---

Тест:

```
words = ["Авто", "Велосипед", "Самолет"]
str_ = "Быстрый автомобиль"
print(is_part_in_list(str_, words))
```

Вывод:

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
words = ["Авто", "Велосипед", "Самолет"]

str = "Быстрый автомобиль"

for s in words:
    if str.lower().find(s.lower()) != -1:
        print("True")
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print(any(word.lower() in str.lower() for word in words))
```

Comment: Нет, не будет так работать. Попробуйте, для начала, посмотреть, что вам выдаст `print([word for word in str])`.

Comment: @strawdog ну да, я забыл о lower(). Но смотреть что мне выдаст печать списка сгенерированного самому по себе не за чем.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с маппингом вместо циклов для разнообразия:

```py
words = ["Авто", "Велосипед", "Самолет"]
text = "Быстрый автомобиль"
print(any(map(text.lower().__contains__, map(str.lower, words))))
```